# Hyper error A javascript error occurred in the main process

Tags: javascript

Anyone know how i fix that ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crt7D.png)

I tried removing all plugins and even changed the " shell : ' ' " ,  to "shell: 'bash.exe'" but the error remains

Comment: JS does not throw desktop alerts. Also there is no bash/shell in JS

Comment: We need to know the context. What are you doing that's triggering the error?

Comment: the error occurs when I start the hyper .                                                                              I forgot to mention but I modified the shell of the 'hyper.js' file according to some tips I saw on github, I also tried uninstalling and installing again, deleting the cache, among other tips but none of them worked . I don't know but I think Hyper may be causing conflicts with other applications or system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Git again...
And I don't have any idea why.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).